# Does closed imply bounded?

Tags: general-topology

> **Definitions:**
>
> **1.** A set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is **bounded** if there exists a number $B$ such that $\mathbf{||x||}\leq B$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in S$, that is , if $S$ is contained in some ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$.
>
> **2.** A set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is **closed** if, whenever $\{\mathbf{x}_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is *convergent* sequence completely contained in $S$, its limit is also contained in $S.$
>
> **3.** A set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is **compact** if and only if it is both closed and bounded.

Does closedness not imply boundedness in general? If so, why does a compact set need to be both closed as well as bounded?

Comment: The whole space is closed, certainly not bounded. The set of points with integer coordinates is closed, not bounded.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The set $\{\,(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid xy=1\,\}$ is closed but not bounded.

Even simpler, $\mathbb R^n$ itself is closed (but not bounded).

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{R}^m$ itself is a closed set. is it bounded?

But in case of Compact sets, they are closed as well as bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.